# NDSolve of pre-defined function

Tags: differential-equations

I have defined function below want to calculate its Numerical differential using NDSolve.

```
x=A*Exp[-Log[y]^2];

f[x_]:= x*(1-x);
```

If i want to look at the change of $f[x]$ with respect to $x'[y]$ using
`NDSolve`. 
what i have to do??

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: do not use capital `D` as a symbol, it is reserved. Additionally you can not use bars `|` for absolute value, use `Abs` and `nabla` has no special meaning.

Comment: on top of the syntax issues your equation is algebraic in `k` so why are you trying to use `NDSolve` ?

Comment: `y` cannot be both a real number (independent variable) and a function head (dependent variable), which is what is happening in your code.  There's a formula in calculus for `y'[x]` in terms of `x'[y]` -- you should probably try that.

Comment: @george2079 first of all thank u so much for bothering, I edited my question. can u still guide.

Comment: @MichaelE2 first of all thank u so much for bothering, I edited my question. can u still guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x[y_] = A*Exp[-Log[y]^2]
f[y_] = x[y]*(1 - x[y])
```

The derivative of `f[y]` with respect to some function `g[y]` is simply

```
 D[f[y],y]/D[g[y],y]
```

so the derivative with respect to the derivative of x[y] is :

```
 result[y_]=D[f[y],y]/D[x[y],{x,2}] //FullSimplify
```

> -(((1 - 2 A E^-Log[y]^2) y Log[y])/(-1 + Log[y] + 2 Log[y]^2))

checking..

```
 A = 1
z[y_] = D[x[y], y]
ParametricPlot[ {z[y], f[y]}, {y, .01, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3/4, 2}, {-1/4, 1/2}}, 
 Epilog -> (Arrow[{{z[#], 
        f[#]}, {z[#], f[#]} + .1 Normalize[{1, result[#]}]} ] & /@ 
    Range[.05, 10, .1])]
```

[image]

Comment: thanku so much, I think it works for me, and if I had $x[y]$ is so complicated that it's always on running. so preferably do $NDSolve$ than what changes i required.

Comment: maybe you want `ND` http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html .  ( I still don't get at all why you want to use `NDSolve` )

Comment: actually my calculation is lengthy in someway,  Further I have to define a function such as $k[y]$, which is sum of different different derivatives as given above, and at the end i have to integrated. If I do this analytically my mathematica running and no answer, but If I do it numerically within a range, it will be conclusive. I hope.